# Redeem script. script hash, witness script and witness program

Tags: transactions, segregated-witness, script, terminology, witness-data

I have a little confusion about naming in Bitcoin.

**Redeem script** is the conditions that will be satisfy. 
For example P2PKH inside P2SH

```
OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <PubKHash> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG == redeem script
```

[In P2SH-P2WPKH the **redeem script** is:](https://bitcoincore.org/en/segwit_wallet_dev/#creation-of-p2sh-p2wpkh-address)

> The P2SH redeemScript is always 22 bytes. It starts with a OP_0,
>   followed by a canonical push of the keyhash (i.e. 0x0014{20-byte
>   keyhash}).

Sometime It call script hash, and during the transaction I need to insert the redeem script in witnessScript. `"witnessScript": "hex",    (string) (required for P2WSH or P2SH-P2WSH) witness script`

Then the redeem script in segwit environment is called redeem script, script hash or witness script?

[Witness program](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki#Witness_program)

> A scriptPubKey (or redeemScript as defined in BIP16/P2SH) that consists of a 1-byte push opcode (for 0 to 16) followed by a data push between 2 and 40 bytes gets a new special meaning.

Witness program depends on script could be scriptPubkey or redeem script?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- The scriptPubKey is the script as it is placed in the transaction output.
- The redeemScript (P2SH only) is the script pushed as the last scriptSig item. In P2SH scripts, the scriptPubKey is equal to `OP_HASH160 <Hash160(redeemScript)> OP_EQUAL`.
- The witness script (P2WSH only) is the script in the last witness stack position.
- The witness program is `Hash160(pubkey)` for P2WPKH, and `SHA256(witness_script)` (not `Hash256(witness_script)`!) for P2WSH. For native segwit outputs the scriptPubKey is `OP_0 <witness_program>`; for P2SH-wrapped segwit outputs the redeemScript is `OP_0 <witness_program>` (and thus the scriptPubKey is `OP_HASH160 <Hash160(OP_0 <witness_script>)> OP_EQUAL`.

Comment: In P2SH-wrapper is `OP_0 <witness_program>` where OP_0 is the witness version?

Comment: Yes, indeed. The OP_0 is the witness version. So far only witness v0 is defined.

Comment: the fourth bullet point. `The witness program is Hash160(pubkey) for P2WPKH, and Hash256(witness_script) for P2WPKH` maybe I think you mean `The witness program is Hash160(pubkey) for P2WPKH, and Hash256(witness_script) for P2WSH` ?

Comment: Yes indeed, fixed.

Comment: @PieterWuille I caught what monkeyUser caught too. It doesn't look like the post has been edited with the fix.

Comment: Now actually fixed. It's SHA256 too, not Hash256.